# Rescale the values for sum of numbers in R

Tags: r, list, data-manipulation, rescale

If I have these data frames

```
df1<- as.numeric(c("20", "25", "15", "50"))

df2<- as.numeric (c("15", "20", "10", "5"))

df3<- as.numeric(c("10", "7", "15", "13"))

my_list <- list(df1, df2, df3)

sum_dat <- as.numeric(c("180", "90", "5"))
```

Here I want the data frames in list my_list i.e. the numbers in df1 to be rescaled such that the sum of df1 (20+25+15+50) is close to or equal to 180, df2 sums to be equal to 90, and df 3 sum equal to 5.

Comment: what is `df1` in the code

Comment: Your code shows `character` class vectors: because you use `c()` they are vectors not data frames, and because you use quotes around the numbers they are `character` not `numeric` class.

Comment: My bad. I have updated the question

Answer (score 2):

We can use `Map` (assuming the `vector`s are all `numeric`)

```
my_list_rescaled <- Map(function(x, y)  x * y/sum(x), my_list, sum_dat)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another base R option using `asplit` + `list2DF` + `colSums`

```
asplit(t(t(df <- list2DF(my_list)) / colSums(df) * sum_dat), 2)
```

gives

```
[[1]]
[1] 32.72727 40.90909 24.54545 81.81818

[[2]]
[1] 27 36 18  9

[[3]]
[1] 1.1111111 0.7777778 1.6666667 1.4444444
```